# Calculate day of month with month, year, day of week and number of week

Tags: php, date

How can I calculate the day of month in PHP with giving month, year, day of week and number of week.
Like, if I have September 2013 and day of week is Friday and number of week is 2, I should get 6. (9/6/2013 is Friday on the 2nd week.)

Comment: The second Friday of September is the 13th isn't it?

Comment: There's no function in PHP to take number-of-week and convert it back into a date, but you can use a loop and `date('W')` to isolate it.

Comment: @Jack True, but I meant it is on the 2nd week.

Comment: How are you counting the weeks then? To me, the first week of September 2013 starts on the 1st.

Comment: @Jack Me too, but it starts on Sunday for me. And Sunday is the last day of week for me.

Comment: This is how my calendar looks for this month: http://prntscr.com/1qgxeg

Comment: Right, so your weekdays start on a Monday :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using [relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) for [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime).

Unfortunately, it's not as straightforward as:

```
strtotime('Friday of second week of September 2013');
```

In order for the weeks to work as you mentioned, you need to call `strtotime()` again with a relative timestamp.

```
$first_of_month_timestamp = strtotime('first day of September 2013');
$second_week_friday = strtotime('+1 week, Friday', $first_of_month_timestamp);
echo date('Y-m-d', $second_week_friday); // 2013-09-13
```

**Note**: Since the first day of the month starts on week one, I've decremented the week accordingly.

Comment: Okay, you were faster with the weekday fix :)

Comment: It's not so much a *fix* as adhering to the spec. While unclear in this case, consider a case where the *first Friday* may not be in the *first week*.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to suggest to just use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) in this fashion:

```
$ts = strtotime('2nd friday of september 2013');
echo date('Y-m-d', $ts), PHP_EOL;
// outputs: 2013-09-13
```

It seems that this is not how you want the calendar to behave? But it is following a (proper) standard :)

Comment: + Good use of the relative format. I agree this is the *proper* standard, but may not match this exact spec.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Yes, your answer would be better in this case; I just keep thinking there should be a better way than this :)

Comment: I know. I spend some time reviewing the `DateTime` docs hoping for the silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

This way its a little longer and obvious but it works.

```
/* INPUT */
$month = "September";
$year = "2013";
$dayWeek= "Friday";
$week = 2;

$start = strtotime("{$year}/{$month}/1"); //get first day of that month
$result = false;
while(true) { //loop all days of month to find expected day
    if(date("w", $start) == $week && date("l", $start) == $dayWeek) {
        $result = date("d", $start);
        break;
    }
    $start += 60 * 60 * 24;
}

var_dump($result); // string(2) "06"
```

Comment: `strtotime()` knows about month names too :)

Comment: it was not working on my machine. i thought it was because my PHP.ini definitions